# Find indices of min or max rainfall values

Tags: python, max, min, indices

I'm having issues having my code display the minimum and maximum values as months instead of values. The code at the bottom for min and max are placeholders but I'm not sure how to tackle this problem.

```
def main():
#List of months
rain_month = ['January', 'February', 'March',' April', \
              'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', \
              'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
#Rainfall list
rainfall = []

#Creates rainfall list for months
index = 0
while index < 12:
    print ("Enter rainfall for ", rain_month [index], ": ",sep='', end = '')
    amount = float(input())
    rainfall.append(amount)
    index += 1

print()

#Total Rainfall
total = 0
for value in rainfall:
    total += value

print("Total Rainfall:", sep="", end="")
print(format(total, ',.2f'))

#Average Rainfall
average = total / len(rainfall)
print("Average Rainfall: ", sep="", end="")
print(format(average, ',.2f'))

#Sort
rainfall.sort()

print(min(rainfall))
print(max(rainfall))
main()
```

Comment: What specifically is your problem? This is kind of vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to get the respective index of a `min` or `max` value you could do something like:

```
index = rainfall.index(min(rainfall))
```

And since you know that the index will correctly lin up with your `rain_month` list, you can use that index to find the month:

```
print(rain_month[rainfall.index(min(rainfall))])
```

However, a better way would be link your `rain_months` and `rainfall` by using a `dict` structure. Since we'd like the `dict` to be ordered we should probably used an `OrderedDict`:

```
import collections
# This is how OrderedDicts are initalized, you give them a list with (key,value) tuples for the order.
rainfall = collections.OrderedDict(
[('January',0),('Feburary',0)]
)

# Do your computation, something like: 
for month in rainfall:
    rainfall[month] = input("Rainfall: ")

print(min(rainfall, key=rainfall.get))
print(max(rainfall, key=rainfall.get))
```

Also, if you're doing `rainfall.sort()`, you can get `min` from `rainfall[0]` and `max` from `rainfall[-1]`. `min` and `max` do not require sorted lists. Also, if you do `sort` you change the order of `rainfall`, while not changing the order of `rain_month`, meaning you can't use the first method I described to get the correct month.

My suggestion would either to be to remove that `sort`, or use the second method.

Comment: Note: this has a caveat in the event of a tied max or min.  It will return the first from the list.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but that's also how `min` and `max` work. Removing `index` wouldn't change this behaviour, as evidenced by the second example using an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: This solved my issue completely! The first method did require that I remove the sort function. I haven't learned about dict structures yet, but I'll look into it. Thanks for your help Darkstarone!